# Samsung Smart TV + Ethernet

Tags: samsung-smartthings, ethernet

I recently got a Samsung smart TV and have set it up with my Google Home via the SmartThings app. Initially I had the TV connected to my network via Wifi while I was routing cables but now I have it connected via Ethernet. When it was on wifi I had no problems asking Google to turn on the TV but now that it's hard-wired it's as if the connection is dead until the TV is powered on. Even from the SmartThings app it says the TV is offline until I turn it on from the remote. Once the TV is on I can use SmartThings or Google Home to turn the TV off.

Internet connection is stable, I can browse content like Netflix and YouTube. Firmware is the latest. It's as if the ethernet port goes offline once the TV is powered off.

The TV is a Samsung Q6DR model, the ethernet is connected to a dumb switch in my media cabinet, and then from there to the router.

Has anyone else run into a similar issue?

Comment: I'm sure you've already tried, but just verifying... have you tried switching back to WiFi and verified that it still works?

Comment: Yeah I just tried switching it back to the Wifi and it seemed fine. I switched it back to ethernet and then removed it from SmartThings and Google Home and re-added everything (Connected via ethernet > Added to SmartThings > Linked SmartThings to GoogleHome) but even in the Samsung SmartThings app it shows as offline if it's connected via ethernet. Only other thing I can think of is that there is an unmanaged switch in between the router and the TV. I'll try plugging it directly to the router and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: When the TV is off, do you still get a link light on either the ethernet socket on the TV or the switch?

Comment: You probably want to specify the model number of the TV. Also, how/where is the TV connected? Via a switch? To the router or AP? Do you have status LEDs on the Ethernet port on either state that give you the link status?

Comment: I updated the question with the TV model and the ethernet set up. It is going to a dumb switch first, so I was going to try connecting it directly to the router to see if it made a difference. The TV doesn't have any link lights on the ethernet port but the switch shows that port as active even when the TV is powered off.